# If we use MVVM, LiveData, does it still make sense to use EventBus or BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, mvvm, broadcastreceiver, android-livedata

If we follow the

> MVVM, LiveData

pattern in our application, does it still make sense to utilize libraries like

> EventBus or BroadcastReceiver

?
Which one is better matched with socket.io???

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on your code’s requirement i.e. what you want to achieve. If its only about sockets then MVVM is fine. You have no need to use other things.